# How to "skip" iteration when building a new array using recursion

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am stuck on something that might be very simple.

I am creating a new array by looping through an existing array using a recursion function yet I can not seem to get the values to stick to the new array. The function, in the end, will be a bit more complex, but for now I need some help.

I have tried soooo many ways to get this to work but I am at a loss right now.

Here is my php function

```
function recursive($array) {

    $newArray = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        if(is_array($value)){
            recursive($value);                              
        }else{
            $newArray[] = $value;
        }   

    }

    return $newArray;

}
```

As is, the new array never gets filled...BUT, if I change this line...

```
recursive($value); // Why can't I just call the recursive function here?
```

...to...

```
$newArray[] = recursive($value); // Instead of having to set a new value to the new array?
```

everything works properly...except that my goal was to create a flat array with only the values.

So my question is, why is it necessary to set a new array value in order to call the recursive function again? Ideally, I want to skip setting a new array value if the value is an array and just continue the loop through the original array.

Comment: You might want to read up on [array merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: I guess I should've made that an answer instead of a comment

Comment: Thank you all for the great answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
function recursive($array) {

    $newArray = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        if(is_array($value)){
            $newArray = array_merge($newArray, recursive($value));                              
        }else{
            $newArray[] = $value;
        }   

    }

    return $newArray;

}
```

...or you could use [special operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
function recursive($array) {

    $newArray = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        if(is_array($value)){
            $newArray += recursive($value);                              
        }else{
            $newArray[] = $value;
        }   

    }

    return $newArray;

}
```

...or pass a [variable by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) like this:

```
function recursive($array, &$newArray = null) {

    if (!$newArray) {
        $newArray = array();
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        if(is_array($value)){
            recursive($value, $newArray);                              
        }else{
            $newArray[] = $value;
        }   

    }

    return $newArray;   
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you a related question? When the $newArray gets returned each cycle, is it always the sum of all the other cycles? I am just confused a bit on what is actually happening when the return is made.

Comment: Yes it is always the sum of all other cycles. Did you read about `array_merge` http://php.net/array_merge ?

Answer (score 1):

use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge the array returned from `recursive($value);` and $newArray

```
$newArray = array_merge($newArray,recursive($value));
```

You can guarantee that `$newArray` will be flat after this, as the previous value of `$newArray` was flat, and `recursive` always returns a flat array, so the combination of both should be a flat array.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing anything with the return from your recursive function. Try this:

```
function recursive($array) {

    $newArray = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        if(is_array($value)){
            // This is what was modified
            $newArray = array_merge($newArray, recursive($value));                              
        }else{
            $newArray[] = $value;
        }   

    }

    return $newArray;

}
```